# Grid forms in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a grid form for a survey question.

```
            value1     value2   value3

option 1      x

option 2                 x

option 3      x
```

Each cell in the grid is a radio button and the radio buttons in a row belong to one radio button group.

My models:

```
class Question
  # title
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer
  # name, position, atype(row/col)  
end
```

Sample data for questions:

```
id  title
--  ------
1   Rate the following movies
```

Sample data for answers:

```
id  question_id  atype   position   name
--  -----------  -----   --------   --------
1   1            row     1          God Father
2   1            row     2          Star Wars
3   1            row     3          Aliens

4   1            col     1          Bad
5   1            col     2          Average
6   1            col     3          Good
```

I am struggling to come up with a Rails approach for creating such a form. To complicate the issue user can save the semi-completed form and complete it at a later time.

What is the best approach for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try formastic http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic There are some great helpers in there that will help you archive your goal.

Comment: I use Formtastic. It doesn't support grid forms.